# How to save datatable first column in array C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have this kind of datatable:

```
Name | CategorieID | FullCategorie_ID
----  -------------  ----------------
 A        1             12  
 B        1             13
 C        5             14
 D        3             15
 E        6             16
```

I want to save the values of column `Name` in an array, I am using this to get the values of a row. E.g. To get the values of the first row I can use the following code.

```
var stringArr =datatable1.Rows[0].ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

But I don't know how to get all the values of the only first column.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I suggest to use LINQ to DataSet for querying DataTable:

```
datatable1.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Name")).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Kami welcome! Btw your problem is `Rows[0]` which gives you firs row of table. Instead you should select data from each row `Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r.ItemsArray[0].ToString())`

Comment: Make sure you add a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions. Reference for AsEnumerable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 7):

Mode classic

```
List<String> stringArr = new List<String>();

// Classic version :-)
for( int a = 0 ; a < datatable1.Rows.Count ; a ++)
{
    stringArr.Add(datatable1.Rows[a]["Name"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I found using LINQ to DataSet more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for posting the "classic" method. Useful in situations where certain compiler versions, libraries and extension methods are not available.

Comment: I appreciate this.  I am trying to find a specific column on a table that doesn't have an ienumerable.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> _data = new List<string>();

foreach (DataRow row in datatable1.Rows)
{
  _data.Add((string)Convert.ToString(row["Name"]));
}

Array test = _data.ToArray();
```

Comment: Please, read carefully sample code from question. Also that does not explain how to get first column only